# Highlight all content inside g tag, whenever mouse above said tag. D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a 'hand-drawn' style chart in d3:
[image: basic bar plot]

Each bar below is a `path` inside of a `g` of class `bar`. When I hover over each `g.bar`, I highlight all paths inside with a basic `mouseover` function:

```
  d3.selectAll('g.bar')
        .on('mouseover', function() {
          d3.select(this).selectAll('path').style('stroke', 'red')
        })
```

[image: highlighted bar in image]

The problem is, **the highlighting only occurs when I hover over the paths, not the entire `g.bar`**.

This makes the highlighting look super glitchy (running a mouse across it repeatedly highlights/unhighlights the path).

My question is: **Is there a way to have all associated paths highlight whenever I'm hovering over the entire `g.bar` outlining the bar itself, and not just when I highlight over the path elements themselves?**

A live-demo of my code is here: https://blockbuilder.org/jwilber/4bd8f5dd73666cdc5a30d7d6481e231a

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add the following css:

```
g.bar {
  pointer-events: bounding-box;
}
```

or directly set the g.bar elements' pointer-events attribute, which in your code would look like:

```
bar.setAttribute('pointer-events', 'bounding-box');
```

this sets up the `g.bar` elements to listen to events anywhere within the actual space that they take up (the bounding box).

*However, the above only works in Chrome.*

Another alternative that seems to work in all the browsers I've tried is to add a transparent rect element to each `g.bar` element (just as a sibling of the path).

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
  let node = rc.rectangle(0, y(d.trick), x(d.count), y.bandwidth());
  bar = roughSvg.appendChild(node);
  bar.setAttribute('class', 'bar');
});

d3.selectAll('g.bar')
  .data(data)
  .append('rect')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', d => y(d.trick))
    .attr('width', d => x(d.count))
    .attr('height', y.bandwidth())
    .attr('fill', 'transparent');
```

I'm guessing that this works because rather than the `g.bar` mouseout event happening whenever it falls between the strokes of the `path`, there is a solid `rect` element filling the space, even if it is transparent.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was actually trying something similar, but much dumber (appending the path to each rectangle, then having the mouseover on the rectangle). This is much cleaner :)